# created macro for dbt is not being detected in macros folder

Tags: dbt

currently getting an error below.

```
Compilation Error in model snowflake_customer_purchases (models/example/snowflake_customer_purchases.sql)
'groupby' is undefined. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps"
```

the macro I created is situated in the macros file -

```
{% macro groupby(n) %} --start and name macro
    GROUP BY
        {% for i in range(1, n + 1) %} 
            {{ i }}
            {% if not loop.last %} , {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

The macro is being called within the following SQL query

```
{{ config(materialized='table', unique_key = 'c_custkey') }}
   select 
    c.c_custkey,
    c.c_name,
    c.c_nationkey,
    sum(o.o_totalprice) as total_order_price
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.customer c
left join snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.orders o
on o.o_custkey = c.c_custkey
{{ groupby(3) }}
```

I have double-checked my syntax and reinstalled my dep. Not sure what else I may have overlooked

Comment: Any reason why not to use dbt_utils' `group_by()` macro?

Comment: I was learning about how to use dbt and the use of macros. i have created other macros within the macros folder but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Have you specified a `macro-paths` in your `dbt_project.yml` that matches the name of the directory where all your macros are?

Comment: I have.....you wouldn't believe it but all of a sudden dbt has picked up the other marcos lol

Answer (score 0):

I performed a dbt run across all models which detected the macros. Initially on performing 'dbt run --models <model_name>' on the specific model of interested. Unsure why the later method did not detect macros.